# Java Record "toString()" mask sensitive fields

Tags: java, record

Is there any way to mask sensitive fields on the automatically generated "toString()" method in Java Records without overriding it? (i.e. Annotations)

i.e.

`public record SomeRecord(..., String apiKey, String password, ...) { }`

Please no "Use Lombok!" answers :)

Comment: The answer is no, there isn't.

Comment: What I feared...but seems like it would be a good addition :)

Comment: An addition at the language level? When overriding `toString` in the very rare event you need to do this is so easy?

Comment: yes @tgdavies that wasn't really serious, but I saw Lombok had a feature-request for this...which ultimately got rejected :)

Comment: As suggestion, try to use public class ReflectionToStringBuilder.

Comment: @FranciscoValadares yes I could do that or just override toString() which is probably what I will end up doing, but the question was if I can avoid that via some trick and reduce boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

I think you can wrap the sensitive info by the object:

```
record SensitiveInfo(String info) {
   public String toString() {
      // add your masking func here
    }
   // other necessary methods to use with info field
}
```

So in your SomeRecord:

```
record SomeRecord(..., SensitiveInfo apiKey, SensitiveInfo password)
```

Comment: The question asks for a way of doing this without overriding `toString`

Comment: I think still a valid response because this solution doesn't override toString in the record. :)

Not necessarily always Strings but the SensitiveInfo could just as easily uses Object#toString().

In my particular situation I am using the records for Spring @ConfigurationProperties so this would be overly complex for the automatic conversions :) but I get what you were thinking.

Comment: @JWT fair enough, I missed that.